# Cual es la estructura para poder ingresar datos en una tabla en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas en postgresql

```
1. id_opcion.- es un dato numérico
2. id_catalogo.- dato numérico
3. descripción.- es texto
4. valor.- es numérico
5. ordenamiento.- es numérico
6. fecha alta.- debe de ser la hora en la que se da de alta el dato
7. activo.- es true o false (como debe de representarse en la estructura)
```

y los datos que quiero ingresar son los siguientes:

```
1. 23400
2. 45
3. UNIDAD DE RESPONSABILIDADES
4. 4
5. 0
6. 17/2/2022
7. ACTIVO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pudiera ser la definición de tu tabla con el ejemplo de insertar datos

```
--definicion de la tabla     
       
CREATE TABLE tu_tabla (
 id_opcion int,
 id_catalogo int,
 descripción text, 
 valor numeric,
 ordenamiento int,
 fecha_alta timestamp,
 activo boolean
);

--para insertar
INSERT INTO tu_tabla values (23400,45,'UNIDAD DE RESPONSABILIDADES',4,0,'2022-02-17',TRUE);
```

puedes consultar los tipos de datos en la [documentacion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype.html), en caso de que requieras modificarlos